# Simple answer needed regarding Mobile Touch Events?

Tags: jquery, html, events, mobile, touch

In college I have been tasked with making a magazine application for mobile devices. I am vaguely familiar HTML5, CSS and JQuery[basic].

What I need to know is how do I initiate a simple swipe event in HTML5? For example If I had two images and i wanted to swipe from the first to the second, or simple how to swipe between HTML5 pages? I have tried looking on here and other web sources but I think I need a basic example the ones online just make no sense to me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: the sample codes & library for ur questions. http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/kitchensink/

Answer (score 0):

There are some JavaScript Touch Libraries you can try,

jQTouch: http://jqtouch.com/

jQuery UI Touch Punch: http://touchpunch.furf.com/

jQuery Mobile: http://jquerymobile.com/

Also there is a Apple documentation explaining list of supported Touch Events,
http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW5

Comment: Another quick question. When your on a page and you turn to the next page is this a swipe event or a drag event? I just can't seem to figure it out?